# TreeView with Textboxes not accepting Asterisks (NumPad)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, treeview

I have a treeview that contain a couple textboxes within and when I try to enter in the asterisks from the NumPad and it doesn't work (Shift + 8 works).

I've been looking around and found that the asterisks triggers an action in the treeview by default.

Is there a way to have the textbox accept the asterisks and not trigger the default treeview action?

Answer (score 1):

Here some code I made based on a reply on msdn. This was used for "+" and "-" from numpad, you could do the same thing with asterisk....

```
 private void UIElement_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var textbox = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
        if (textbox != null && (e.Key == Key.Add || e.Key == Key.Subtract))
        {


            string signToInsert = e.Key == Key.Add ? "+" : "-";
            if (textbox.SelectionLength == 0)
            {
                int caretPosition = textbox.CaretIndex;
                textbox.Text = textbox.Text.Insert(caretPosition, signToInsert);
                textbox.CaretIndex = caretPosition + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                int selectionStart = textbox.SelectionStart;
                int selectionLength = textbox.SelectionLength;

                string newText = "";
                newText += textbox.Text.Substring(0, selectionStart);
                newText += signToInsert;
                newText += textbox.Text.Substring(selectionStart + selectionLength);
                textbox.Text = newText;

                textbox.CaretIndex = selectionStart + 1;
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the textbox to accept the asterisk and not trigger the default treeview action use the built in built-in WPF `InputBindings`. Set up a `KeyBinding` to `ApplicationCommands.NotACommand` with `Key.Multiply` as the key gesture. Set up the KeyBindings at the TreeView level as shown below.

```
<TreeView.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Gesture="Multiply" Command="ApplicationCommands.NotACommand" /> 
</TreeView.InputBindings>
```

Be aware that this will disable the command bound to `Key.Multiply` i.e. NumPad asterisk. To quote the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.notacommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on the `ApplicationCommands.NotACommand` property:

> This command is always ignored and does not handle the input event that caused it. This provides a way to turn off an input binding built into an existing control.